# SQL Multiple Parameter Values

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

What options are available in SQL 2005 to pass in multiple values to store procedures

Psuedo codes

In C# code

```
    List<string> myApplicationList;
    .... (code to assign values)
    **Construct parameter list**
    Call stored procedure [spSelectMaster] with myApplicationList
```

SQL stored procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [Ecn].[spSelectMaster]
        **Need to declare parameter here but not sure what this would be**
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        SELECT *
        FROM [dbo].[Master]
        WHERE [Master].[ApplicationKey] IN (@ApplicationList)
    END
    GO
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in support for arrays in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL, but you can work around this:

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#CSV)

[How to pass a list of values or array to SQL Server stored procedure?](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm)